# How can i filter items from a list that those items contain specific text by clicking in a checkbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list that contains 6 items/divs. How can i filter the items that contain specific text by clicking/select a checkbox? For the following example i want to filter the items that contains the word "green" when i select the checkbox labeled "green" and so on.

So when i click the "Green" checkbox i want to hide all other divs that doesn't contain the word "Green" and show them back on checkbox deselect.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#box1').change(function() {
 if($('.item-tag').text()==="Green"){
  $('.m3-item').show();
  } else {
    $('.m3-item').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #646464;
}

.filters {

  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5% 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

.m3-item {
padding:5px;
margin:3px;
background:#eee;
width:80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <div class="continents" style="font-size:12px;">
    
    <div>Green
      <input type="checkbox" id="box1" />
    </div>
    <div>Red
      <input type="checkbox" id="box2" />
    </div>
   
   </div>

</div>

<div class="listItems">
<div class="m3-item"><div class="item-tag">Green</div></div>
<div class="m3-item"><div class="item-tag">Red</div></div>
<div class="m3-item"><div class="item-tag">Blue</div></div>
<div class="m3-item"><div class="item-tag">Green</div></div>
<div class="m3-item"><div class="item-tag">Red</div></div>
<div class="m3-item"><div class="item-tag">Green</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like a case for [:contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: @Paulie_D could you please take a look again? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not very efficient, but it can work with a simple change to your jquery code:

```
$('#box1').on('change', function() {
    $('.item-tag').each(function() {
        if($(this).text()==="Green"){
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    })
});
```